# AWK help - multi-line output with repeated variables

Tags: list, file, variables, awk

I have a file with groups of information split up in vertical lines.

```
group_name  
email1  
email2  
email3

group_name2  
email1  
email2  

group_name3  
email1
```

etc....

I need help to get it to  output to a file in this format:

```
group_name email1  
group_name email2  
group_name email3  
group_name2 email1  
group_name2 email2   
group_name3 email1
```

etc...

currently I am running this command:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; RS=""} {print $1,$2}' output.txt > output2.txt
```

but the output obviously isn't what I'm looking for as it only looks at the group_name and first email line, then ignores the next few (if they exist) and moves on to the next group.

How do I get this to loop through all lines until there are none, then move to the next group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` in [paragraph mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html) and do:

```
$ echo "group_name
email1
email2
email3

group_name2
email1
email2

group_name3
email1

" | awk -v RS= '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s ", $i;} print ""}'
```

Prints:

```
group_name email1 email2 email3 
group_name2 email1 email2 
group_name3 email1
```

Or, your format:

```
echo "group_name
email1
email2
email3

group_name2
email1
email2

group_name3
email1

" | awk -v RS= '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s %s\n", $1, $i;}}'
```

Prints:

```
group_name email1
group_name email2
group_name email3
group_name2 email1
group_name2 email2
group_name3 email1
```

Then just redirect `stdout` to the desired output file:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s %s\n", $1, $i;}}' in_file >out_file
```

(If there is a possibility of horizontal spaces in the group name or email names, add `awk -v RS= -v FS=$'\n' '...'` so that the field separator is solely a new line.)